# Conda package for Klein (Twisted micro web framework)

Tags: twisted, klein-mvc

Is there a conda channel that contains "klein" package?

http://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Found it here

https://anaconda.org/auto/klein

```
conda install -c auto klein
```